# SSRS: Remove empty spaces in report

Tags: reporting-services

Below is the output I'm getting. Even when all options are collapsed, I have a ton of empty space that I'd love to eliminate. I have tried row visibility and textbox visibility, but those are currently working to keep my expand/collapse working correctly, I believe. I also tried looking in the properties pane (F4) and messing with the CanGrow/CanShrink properties but no luck in changing output.

How do I fix this?

[image]

**UPDATE:** Here is the design view

[image]

Comment: It looks like you're change the visibility of the DAY **Group** instead of the Row Visibility for the data. The Group data is not visible but the rows still are. A pic of the design view (with the table selected so the grouping lines are visible on the left) would be helpful along with where the Visibility is.

Comment: I think it's the text boxes that have been hidden rather than the group. Hiding and toggling the row group is the correct way to do it as it encompasses all objects in the group even when they are on multiple rows.

Answer (score 0):

Undo all the visibility changes you have made, and probably the undo the group expand collapse changes you made so you have a fresh start.. Even better, create the tablix from scratch again.

Then on the row group properties under the main design window, right-click the row group you want to initially hide and choose properties.

On the visibility tab.. Select "Hide" (if you want the rows in this group to be hidden when the report opens). Then Check the box "Display can be toggled by this report item" and choose the name of text box from the parent group that you want to click to expand. For example, if you were hiding the 'day' group, selected the text box that contains your month name (default this will be the same as the field name).

That's it, just those two steps to achieve what you want. You can repeat this process the month group using year as the toggle etc..

Comment: That's pretty much what I started with. Using the Hide and 'toggled by' is the only way to facilitate the expand/collapse so far as I know, so pardon my skepticism with your answer.

Comment: No problem. I did actually create a step by step for this last night but by the time I had pasted the last image in, you had deleted your question! Anyway. I have a fully working report that does exactly what you describe using the method I outlined above. Also, make sure all the can grow/shrink properties are back to default. I've written a lot of these style reports so I can guarantee that this works. If you still have issues, I will recreate the answer I wanted to post last night.

Comment: I deleted another question, regarding how to do grouping, but that's only because I figured out how to get the output I was looking for. Now it's just a matter of ridding this ugly blank space! Sincere apologies, I didn't think anyone had gone through any effort during the time I had it up, so thank you for taking that time. I recreated my tablix and ONLY did row visibility, but still having same issue.

Comment: You don't need to touch the row visibility only the group visibility. I did just notice you have a group for pay_cleintfileno1. Make sure all grouping levels that need to be collapsed have been set to use the parent level to toggle. I'll post a step by step on a similar report later this evening hopefully. It's not got as many levels but the principle is identical.

Comment: Alan, I would love to see your step-by-step if you wouldn't mind taking the time. I understand grouping, but getting this to work as intended is new territory for me, and I'd really love to understand it. Thanks!

Answer (score 0):

Ultimately, I found a solution by using Report Builder to do what I wanted it to do. I was able to get the output by visually confirming the template. What's strange, is that when I created it, I then opened it up in Visual Studio to see how it differed, and there was absolutely no visibility changes. Meaning, no cells or rows had the Hide option checkboxed.

Furthermore, it differs from what I built previously by not having the extra columns within the grouping, and maybe that's where the extra blank space was coming from. But unfortunately, I found no quantifiable explanation to better help others.

[image]

Comment: The difference I can see if that you do not have a details group in the image in your answer but you do in your original question. However the pay_fileclientno1 group in your original question does not have a header row, so my guess is that it is that group that was no being collapsed.
Anyway, glad you got it sorted.